# C++: How to define a virtual function with generic return type?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to define a base a class in C++ that has pure virtual methods to be implemented by children classes.

I would like to define setter and getter functions for basic types in the base class, but I would like the derived class to be able to determine the basic type of the getter and setter. For instance my base class would look like this:

```
class Value
{
public:
   Value();

   template <class T>;
   virtual T getValue() = 0;
   virtual void setValue(T val) = 0;
}
```

and my child class would look something like this:

```
class IntValue : public Value
{
public:
   IntValue();

   template <class T>
   T getValue() {return _val};
   void setValue(T val) {_val = val};
private:
   int _val;
}
```

Of course the above code does not work. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've hit the `virtual` wall...

Comment: If the number of types are limited you can use boost's `variant` type to implement a limited amount of dynamic typing.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: You could do the same with `boost::any` for an unrestricted set of types -- but you pay for that with a level of indirection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, rewriting your code to

```
template <class T>
class Value
{
public:
    Value();
    virtual T getValue() = 0;
    virtual void setValue(T val) = 0;
};


class IntValue : public Value<int>
{
public:
    IntValue();

    int getValue() {return _val;}
    void setValue(int val) {_val = val;}
private:
    int _val;
};
```

should work

Comment: +1 -- this doesn't answer the OP's question, but it probably achieves a similar effect to what the OP really wanted given their naming of the classes and problem description.

Comment: In this case, `IntValue` is not a subclass of `Value`.  As such, the `virtual` keyword means nothing.  You wouldn't be able to define a function that takes a `Value*` and pass an `IntValue` to it.

Comment: @Steven: Indeed; you can't even create a `Value` or `Value*` in the first place; it'd have to be a `Value<T>` or `Value<T>*` for some type.

Comment: So, really that means I'm better off defining the setters and getters with in the children classes, and remove it from my base class. Since I have to use `Value<T>*` but not `Value*`, which will complicate things for me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking for is not possible. In order to generate the right entries in the `vtbl` (or whatever similar structure the compiler might be using), the compiler needs to know what entries are going to be needed in the base class specifically. You can't just return a different type in a derived class and expect the base class to "know" about it in that way; as that would require a modification of the definition of the function template in the base class.

An example of how you might do that kind of modification of the base class using a *class template* (rather than a *function template*) can be seen in [J_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820912/82320), but that still doesn't match your problem description exactly, because you wouldn't be able to create a `Value` and treat it polymorphicly.

C++ templates are essentially "fancy-pants find and replace" with the type -- when the compiler instantiates the function template, it generates a plain function with the typenames replaced. Note that this is very different than C# or Java "generics", which are completely different and rely on runtime support and a layer of indirection to achieve a similar effect. (Note though that this "find and replace" respects precedence rules and such, unlike C preprocessor macros :) )

If you really think about it too, this pattern does not make sense. What would this really look like on the client side of things?

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value();
    //Imagine if this were possible...
    template <class T>;
    virtual T getValue() = 0;
    virtual void setValue(T val) = 0;
}

class IntValue : public Value
{
public:
    IntValue();
    int getValue() {return _val};
    void setValue(int val) {_val = val};
private:
    int _val;
}

class FloatValue : public Value
{
public:
    FloatValue();
    float getValue() {return _val};
    void setValue(float val) {_val = val};
private:
    float _val;
}
```

Now, you go to use this class:

```
void example(Value * ptr)
{
    //What could you possibly say the type of "bar" is? There's no type that works!
    ???? bar = ptr->getValue();
    delete ptr;
}

int main()
{
    example(new IntValue());
    example(new FloatValue());
}
```

As such, even if this were allowed, it wouldn't make much sense. You'd always have to downcast all the time, which would mean that the `virtual` keyword would be meaningless anyway.

Comment: I wish more people really understood what templates really are.  Templates are macros with type checking and other fanciness.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @Billy ONeal said about a class template, this may work for your purposes:

```
template<typename Type>
class Value
{
public:
    virtual Type getValue() = 0;
};

class IntValue : public Value<int>
{
public:
    IntValue(int value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

    int getValue()
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Comment: How does this differ from J_D's solution?

Comment: It's different in that I didn't see his solution (oddly, since I saw yours). I did, however, upvote his solution.